# при попытке создать консольное приложение выходит ошибка о том ,что .net core cdk не установлен

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Решил изучить `C#`, установил VS code , но при попытке создать консоль с помощью команды `dotnet new console` выходит:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download.
```

перешел по ссылке установил , но история та же самая.

Comment: Консоль попробуйте закрыть и открыть заново.

Answer (score 0):

Решение данной ошибки описано в [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6095) на гитхаб, вот этот [комментарий](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6095#issuecomment-809006602).

1. Сначала проверить расположение `dotnet`, используя команду `where.exe dotnet`
2. Если вывод будет содержать две строки, примерно так

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
   C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
   ```

   То это значит, что установлено две версии для 32 и 64 разрядных систем. И здесь важен порядок нахождения их в системных переменных
3. Исправить можно поменяв их местами, расположив 64 разрядную выше 32, в системных переменных. Как это сделать в картинках можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5962#issuecomment-780084535)